# How to pass parameters to ui:include that inside of c:forEach tag

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jstl

We are trying to create a list with iterating an entity with `ui:include.`

my `.xhtml` file is like;

```
<c:forEach items="#{entityHome.list}" var="entityId">
    <ui:include src="/some.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="id" value="#{entityId}" />
    </ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

We have already created a `.xhtml` file to visualize single entity. Not we want a list of all entities. Firstly we were using a `h:dataGrid` but according to [this](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) we changed it to `c:forEach`.

Now when page is rendered, fields in `/some.xhtml` are empty. I think we cant pass parameter to `ui:include`. By *cant* i mean for this situation.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include some.xhtml? I'm curious what do you need id param for.

Comment: well...what im trying to do is; i have a page to visualize entities. And some.xhtml is controled by a manager bean(entityHome). if entity home is _managed_, i'm querying store and bind instance to page basically. With this code for loop is not looping all includes. Show just one page and that page's values are empty. So that makes me to think i cant pass parameter to some.xhtml page.

Comment: You should check what entityHome.getList() returns when component tree is built. If this value can change without tree reconstruction you may run into problems described in your referenced article. Maybe set a breakpoint on getter under debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, what I did to solve it was putting another ui:param above the ui:include, and then link that param to the param inside the ui:include :

```
<c:forEach items="#{entityHome.list}" var="entityId">
    <ui:param name="someId" value="#{entityId}"/>
    <ui:include src="/some.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="id" value="#{someId}" />
    </ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

This seemed to do the trick for me.