# How to get ui:param of ui:include wrapped in c:forEach in JSF ManagedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass parameters to ui:include that inside of c:forEach tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526332/how-to-pass-parameters-to-uiinclude-that-inside-of-cforeach-tag)

This one ( [How do I set Managed Bean field to the value of a ui:param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982987/how-do-i-set-managed-bean-field-to-the-value-of-a-uiparam) ) is working well. If I'm looping the ui:include with the help of a JST c:forEach the Facelet Attributes (ui:param) always resolves to null.

```
<c:forEach items="#{myList} var="myItem">
    <ui:include src="#{myItem.myPage}">
        <ui:param name="myVar" value="#{myItem.myData}"/>
    </ui:include>   
</c:forEach>
```

And I'm trying to resolve the Facelet Attribute within a JSF Managed Bean (which is exclusively for exact one ui:include per JSF view)

```
FacesContext facesCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FaceletContext faceletCtx = (FaceletContext) facesCtx.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
Object myVar = faceletCtx.getAttribute("myVar");
```

As long as I'm not looping the (no c:forEach) this approach works well. But after introducing the c:forEach myVar is always null.

**What is JSTL c:forEach changing at the facelet attributes (names)? How can I still access them in my Backing Bean?**

Unfortunately FaceletContext does not expose any methods to list all facelet attributes, so I might "find" them on my own ... :S

Answer (score 1):

Thing is that `c:forEach`is not ment to use with JSF. So that's why we have `<ui:repeat>` which does basically the same but it's part of the JSF component tree. Further explanation for example [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362487/dynamic-uiinclude-inside-uirepeat-is-there-a-simple-solution#3362534) and [belonging description](http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/blog/c:foreach-vs-ui:repeat-in-facelets) ... I thought JSF (2.X) got native support for selected JSTL Tags (incl. forEach), so it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Panda updated link: https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat